# why magento rest api returning more order items than ordered?

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api

I placed order using [magento graphQL](https://magento.stackexchange.com/) api, order placed successfully and listed in my orders section in website. I placed order of 1 product. In website's order detail page it displaying 1 item ordered. But when I fetch order items data using rest api `rest/default/V1/orders/000000004`, it gives me 2 item ordered.

I think there may be something naming issue, because I ordered,

```
product name : Portia Capri
size : 29
color : Green
```

Now, when I fetch ordered items data using rest api it returning 2 items which includes **Portia Capri** and **Portia Capri-29-Green**.

Please anyone can help me how to get only ordered item ?

Answer (score 0):

When place order configurable product then magento create 2 entry `sales_order_item`

Check this Query

```
SELECT * FROM `sales_order_item` WHERE `order_id` = 'your_order_id'
```

Comment: Ok, but how I can get only ordered item ?

Comment: You can get only visible item use this $order->getAllVisibleItems()

Comment: Means where I pass this condition ? I am using this api to get orders : https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4-admin/tag/orders#operation/salesOrderRepositoryV1GetListGet

Comment: You need to mange with coding

Comment: I am using this rest api to build mobile app. How can I mange with coding there ?